# Unclassifiable statement despite having declared the indicated variable?

Tags: fortran

For some reason when I compile my code I am given the single error:

```
 49 | sum=sum(num)
    | 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

But I have already declared it in my subroutine:

```
subroutine positivesum(a) 
implicit none
real::sum,x
character(len=*)::a
integer:: n,stat
real,allocatable,dimension(:):: num

open (2,file=a)
n=-1
stat=0
do while (stat==0)
    n=n+1
    read(2,*,iostat=stat)x
end do

allocate(num(n))
rewind(2)

do i=1,n
    read(2,30) num(i)
end do 
30 format (f6.2)

sum=sum(num)
write(*,*) sum

deallocate(num)

end subroutine positivesum
```

What I want is to add up all the numbers allocated in a file which I have called (not shown here), and have it written in my terminal, but despite having declared the variable 'sum', it gives me this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you rename the `sum` variable to `bobby` instead?

Comment: Oh, yes it does. Okay so that would just mean I need use variables that are not used as functions, got it. Thank you !